# TestNG - how to change the DefaultSuite and DefaultTest to your choice of name in the results file

Tags: testng

I am running TestNG with Selenium 2.0 and Eclipse. My results get generated in the /test-output folder. The index.html and emailable-report.html files show the test name as default test and suite name as default suite. I would like to customize it and use the names of my choice. How do I do that?

So far I have tried following approaches.
1. In the run configurations, add the arguments testname and suitename - not work
2. Use testng.xml file to run the tests instead of class name - not work. It has its own issues and I will post a separate question :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use template XML file: http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-listeners

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the suite name and test case name under execution as following.

To customize the Suite name, Add the attribute  name to the suite tag in **testing.xml**

```
   Eg: <suite name="MySuiteName">
```

To customize the  Test Case name,Add the attribute name to the test tag in **testing.xml**

```
   Eg:  <test name="MyTestName">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use default testng.xml or make duplicate of this in a different name e.g. smoketest.xml and customise, add required test path using  tag.Right click and run as testNG test suite. See example code for xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Smoke Test Suite" preserve-order="true" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">
 
 <test name="SMOKETEST">
     <classes> 
          <class name="com.automation.mycompany.project.packagename.classname"/>   
     </classes>
   </test>
```